# Return multiple IDs from a function and use the result in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I have this function that returns me all children of a tree node:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_category_get_childs_v2(id_pai integer)
RETURNS integer[] AS
$BODY$

DECLARE

ids_filhos integer array;


BEGIN

SELECT array ( 

SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category_id IN (
(WITH RECURSIVE parent AS
(
    SELECT category_id , parent_id  from category WHERE category_id = id_pai
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.category_id , t.parent_id FROM parent
    INNER JOIN category t ON parent.category_id =  t.parent_id
)

SELECT category_id FROM  parent
WHERE category_id <> id_pai
) )


 ) into ids_filhos; 

return ids_filhos;

END;
```

and I would like to use it in a select statement like this:

```
select * 
from teste1_elements 
where category_id in (select * from fn_category_get_childs_v2(12))
```

I've also tried this way with the same result:

```
select * 
from teste1_elements
where category_id=any(select * from fn_category_get_childs_v2(12)))
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 1: select * from teste1_elements where category_id in (select *...
                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The function returns an integer array, is that the problem?

```
 SELECT * from fn_category_get_childs_v2(12)
```

retrieves the following array (`integer[]`):

```
 '{30,32,34,20,19,18,17,16,15,14}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function returns an integer array, is that the problem?

Yes.  Typically, if you want to use `where category_id in (select * from fn_category_get_childs_v2(12))` you'd want your function to return a set of rows, rather than an array.  Something like `RETURNS SETOF integer`

The [example in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN56274) may help:

It's also possible to use your existing function, however you'll have to use different syntax to compare against the array.

I think this should be closer:

```
select * 
from teste1_elements 
where category_id = any(fn_category_get_childs_v2(12))
```

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the function to return a setof integer and it works great! By the way, how should be the syntax to compare against the array? One more time, thank you a lot.

Comment: Based on some quick testing, `where category_id = any(fn_category_get_childs_v2(12))` should work, if you're still returning `int[]`

Comment: Yes you're right. Didn't know I could call a function without "select.." ! By the way, with a little and quick benchmark showed me that the solution with the setof integer is a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive `WITH` query at the core can be simplified to:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
   SELECT category_id
   FROM   category
   WHERE  parent_id = id_pai

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT c.category_id
   FROM   children ch
   JOIN   category c ON c.parent_id = ch.category_id
   )
SELECT *
FROM   children;
```

Shorter, cleaner, faster.
To wrap that into a function, I'd use a plain [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) (instead of a [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) for the simple case:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_cat_children(_id_pai int, OUT category_id int)
  RETURNS SETOF int
  LANGUAGE SQL AS
$func$
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
   SELECT c.category_id
   FROM   category c
   WHERE  c.parent_id = $1

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT c.category_id
   FROM   children ch
   JOIN   category c ON c.parent_id = ch.category_id
   )
TABLE children;
$func$;
```

I use an [`OUT` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to assign the column name `category_id` to the resulting column - simplifies the join later. Be aware that this is visible everywhere in the body. That's why you have to table qualify the column `c.category_id` to make it unambiguous.

#### Argument names or positional parameters

A.k.a "ordinal" or "numeric references".

In reply to your comment:
Since Postgres 9.2 arguments can be referenced by name **or** position (`$1`, `$2`, ...). [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-BASE-FUNCTIONS):

> Arguments of a SQL function can be referenced in the function body
> using either names or numbers.

That's not the case for Postgres 9.1 or earlier, where only ordinal references are understood in the function body.

PL/pgSQL functions allow argument *names* since version 8.0.

Your resulting query is simpler with `JOIN` syntax instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   teste1_elements t
JOIN   f_cat_children(12) USING (category_id)
```

Or just do everything in a single query and no function:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
    SELECT category_id
    FROM   category
    WHERE  parent_id = id_pai

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c.category_id
    FROM   children ch
    JOIN   category c ON c.parent_id = ch.category_id
    )
SELECT t.*
FROM   children
JOIN   teste1_elements t USING (category_id);
```

Should be a bit faster, yet.

Comment: Hy Erwin Brandstetter! Once again thank you for helping me. I've tried to create the function in Plain SQL instead of plpgsql, but I get the following error : `ERROR:  column "_id_pai" does not exist
LINE 7:       WHERE  c.parent_id = _id_pai`. Doesn't the function recognize the variable "_id_pai" as an INPUT value?

Comment: @NewK: Ah sorry, that would require the new Postgres 9.2. I amended the answer and added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the explanation. I've upgraded to postgresql 9.2 too :)