# Split given string and prepare case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, set-returning-functions, unnest

**Table**: table_name

```
create table table_name
(
given_dates timestamp,
set_name varchar
);
```

**Insertion of records**:

```
insert into table_name values('2001-01-01'),('2001-01-05'),('2001-01-10'),
                 ('2001-01-15'),('2001-01-20'),('2001-01-25'),
                 ('2001-02-01'),('2001-02-05'),('2001-02-10'),
                 ('2001-02-15');
```

Now I want to update set_name for some dates.

**For example**:

I want to update table like this:

```
given_dates    set_name 
----------------------
2001-01-01      s1
2001-01-05      s1
2001-01-10      s2
2001-01-15      s2
2001-01-20
2001-01-25
2001-02-01
2001-02-05
2001-02-10
2001-02-15
```

**Note**: The `given_dates` and `set_name` are pass a parameter because of they are dynamic. I may pass 2 sets 
as shown above `s1,s2` or may pass 4 sets according to the requirement.

So I need the dynamic case statement for update the `set_name`.

**Given two parameters**:

```
declare p_dates varchar := '2001-01-01to2001-01-05,2001-01-10to2001-01-15';

declare p_sets varchar := 's1,s2';
```

Well I can do this by using following static script:

**Static Update statement**:

```
update table_name
SET set_name = 
CASE  
when given_dates between '2001-01-01' and '2001-01-05' then 's1'
when given_dates between '2001-01-10' and '2001-01-15' then 's2'
else '' 
end;
```

The above update statement does the job done but statically.

Like the same way to update table I want to prepare only case statement which should be dynamic which can change as per the parameters `(p_dates,p_sets)` changes.

**Questions**:

1. How to split the given dates that is `p_dates`? (I have `to` keyword in between two dates.)
2. How to split the given sets that is `p_sets`? (I have ',' comma in between two set_names.)
3. How to prepare dynamic case statement after splitting the `p_dates` and `p_sets`?

---

This question relates to [Dynamic case statement using SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428544/dynamic-case-statement-using-sql-server-2008-r2/27428811#27428811), which is the same thing but for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: check out the `string_to_array()` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: You might also want to check out [regexp_split_to_table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). But I am not sure if going directly to a table and bypassing the array is better in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clean setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  given_date date
, set_name varchar
);
```

Use a singular term as column name for a *single* value.
The data type is obviously [`date` and not a `timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

To transform your text parameters into a useful table:

```sql
SELECT unnest(string_to_array('2001-01-01to2001-01-05,2001-01-10to2001-01-15', ',')) AS date_range
     , unnest(string_to_array('s1,s2', ',')) AS set_name;
```

"Parallel unnest" is handy but has its caveats. Postgres **9.4** adds a clean solution, Postgres **10** eventually sanitized the behavior of this. See below.

### Dynamic execution

#### Prepared statement

Prepared statements are only visible to the creating session and die with it. [Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html)

> Prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database session.

[`PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) *once per session*:

```sql
PREPARE upd_tbl AS
UPDATE tbl t
SET    set_name = s.set_name
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(string_to_array($1, ',')) AS date_range
        , unnest(string_to_array($2, ',')) AS set_name
   ) s
WHERE t.given_date BETWEEN split_part(date_range, 'to', 1)::date
                       AND split_part(date_range, 'to', 2)::date;
```

Or use tools provided by your client to prepare the statement.
Execute n times with arbitrary parameters:

```
EXECUTE upd_tbl('2001-01-01to2001-01-05,2001-01-10to2001-01-15', 's1,s4');
```

#### Server-side function

Functions are persisted and visible to *all* sessions.

[`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) *once*:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upd_tbl(_date_ranges text, _names text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
UPDATE tbl t
SET    set_name = s.set_name
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(string_to_array($1, ',')) AS date_range
        , unnest(string_to_array($2, ',')) AS set_name
   ) s
WHERE  t.given_date BETWEEN split_part(date_range, 'to', 1)::date
                        AND split_part(date_range, 'to', 2)::date
$func$;
```

Call n times:

```
SELECT f_upd_tbl('2001-01-01to2001-01-05,2001-01-20to2001-01-25', 's2,s5');
```

<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce7c3/1)</sub>

### Superior design

Use array parameters (can still be provided as string literals), a [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) type (both pg 9.3) and the [new parallel `unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) (pg **9.4**).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upd_tbl(_dr daterange[], _n text[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
UPDATE tbl t
SET    set_name = s.set_name
FROM   unnest($1, $2) s(date_range, set_name)
WHERE  t.given_date <@ s.date_range
$func$;
```

[`<@` being the "element is contained by" operator.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)

Call:

```
SELECT f_upd_tbl('{"[2001-01-01,2001-01-05]"
                  ,"[2001-01-20,2001-01-25]"}', '{s2,s5}');
```

Details:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/passing-arrays-to-stored-procedures-in-postgres/27854382#27854382)

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. In the Superior design part in `function f_upd_tbl()` getting an error `ERROR:  function unnest(daterange[], text[]) does not exist
LINE 7: FROM   unnest($1, $2) s(date_range, set_name)`. I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 version.

Comment: But anyway I got clear with the concept. Thank you so much. I wish if there is 1000 up vote button I can click that.

Comment: @MAK: `unnest()` with multiple parameters is new in Postgres 9.4, as noted.

Comment: Can you please help me for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562244/invalid-count-and-sum-in-cross-tab-query-using-postgresql

Comment: The omission of `_dr` and `_n` in the func of "Superior Design" threw me at first, but I realize those are being passed to `unnest` as $1 and $2.  And then table `s` is created on the fly with two named columns (`date_range` and `set_name`) and dynamically typed based on the unnest , correct?  How long / where does table `s` exist?

Comment: @Randall Function parameters can be referenced by name or ordinal position. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604751/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358378/939860 The derived table `s` only exists within the scope of the same *query*.

Answer (score 0):

**String_to_array**

```
declare p_dates varchar[] := string_to_array('2001-01-01,2001-01-05,
2001-01-10,2001-01-15*2001-01-01,2001-01-05,2001-01-10,2001-01-15','*');
declare p_sets varchar[]  := string_to_array('s1,s2',',');
declare p_length integer=0;
declare p_str  varchar[];
declare i integer;
select array_length(p_dates ,1) into p_count;

for i in 1..p_count loop

  p_str  := string_to_array( p_dates[i],',')   

  execute 'update table_name
  SET set_name = 
  CASE  
  when given_dates between'''|| p_str  [1] ||''' and '''|| p_str  [2] 
  ||''' then ''' || p_sets[1] ||'''
  when given_dates between '''|| p_str  [3] ||''' and '''
  || p_str  [4] ||''' then ''' || p_sets[2] ||'''
  else '''' 
  end';
end loop;
```

Comment: What if there is a 5 sets? You need to write again when and condition 5 time according to your script.

Comment: There is an error: `invalid type name "array_length(p_dates ,1) into p_count"`. And even I don't want to use loop because of performance issues. There might be 100's of sets to update due to this the looping is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

now we can use `datemultirange`.

```
create or replace function f_upd_tbl_multirange(_dr datemultirange , _n text[])
    returns void as
$func$
UPDATE tbl t
SET    set_name = s.set_name
FROM   unnest($1,$2) s(date_range,set_name)
WHERE  t.given_date <@ s.date_range
$func$ language sql;
```

run it.

```
SELECT f_upd_tbl_multirange(
    '{[''2022-01-01'',''2022-01-05''],[''2022-02-06'',''2022-02-25'']}', '{s2,s5}');
```