# Bulk update with associative array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update, string-parsing

Let's say I have an associative array (defined in another language) like so:

```
apply = {
  'qwer': ['tju', 'snf', 'rjtj', 'sadgg']
  'asdf': ['rtj', 'sfm', 'rtjt', 'adjdj']
  ...
  'zxcv': ['qwr', 'trj', '3w4u', '3tt3']
}
```

And I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE apples (
id integer,
name varchar(10),
key varchar(10),
value varchar(10)
);
```

I want to apply an update where if `apples.value` is in one of the lists of the `apply` variable, then set the `apples.key` to the key of the array. If `apples.value` was `tju` then set `apples.key` to `qwer`.

My current approach looks like this (mixing PostgreSQL with any procedural language):

```
for key in apply.keys:
  UPDATE apples SET key=$key
  FROM (SELECT unnest(array($apply[key])) AS value) AS update_table
  WHERE value=update_table.value
```

I want to do this in a single statement.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this in a literal single statement.  With a function (stored procedure) or a smart DB library in your code sure, but as straight SQL, I'm skeptical.  I've upvoted the question though because It's interesting and I'd like to be proven wrong.

Comment: @user3137702: There is always a way. Postgres has a large arsenal of string functions. Typically, it would be smarter / less error-prone to transform to compatible data types in the source language, though. I added a proof of concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proof of concept for the given example, with the string formatted exactly as you display:

Demonstrating a prepared statement, like your client probably uses.

```
PREPARE my_update AS
UPDATE apples a
SET    key = upd.key
FROM  (
   SELECT trim (split_part(key_val, ': ', 1), ' ''') AS key
        , string_to_array(translate(split_part(key_val, ': ', 2), '[]''', ''), ', ') AS val_arr
   FROM   unnest(string_to_array(trim($1, E'{}\n'), E'\n')) key_val
   ) upd
WHERE  a.value = ANY(upd.val_arr);
```

`EXECUTE` in the same session any number of times:

```
EXECUTE my_update($assoc_arr${
  'qwer': ['tju', 'snf', 'rjtj', 'sadgg']
  'asdf': ['rtj', 'sfm', 'rtjt', 'adjdj']
  'zxcv': ['qwr', 'trj', '3w4u', '3tt3']
}$assoc_arr$);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c7ca0/2)

Related:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)
- [Split given string and prepare case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018991/split-given-string-and-prepare-case-statement/28220532#28220532)

But I would rather process the type in its original language and pass `key` and `val_arr` separately.